# How to add multiple curves using amchart depends on your unique data

Tags: jquery, mysql, codeigniter, amcharts

i have my data in mysql that look like this.

```
ID | Project_id | current_usage |
1        1            10
2        1            20
3        1            30
4        1            40
5        2            20
6        2            40
7        3            10
8        3            20
```

how can i make dynamic curves on my line chart using amchart, that will depend on the uniqueness of the project_id.

i already have the code, but it only works for one curve only, how can i know make a seperate curve from it that will depend on the project_id. here is my existing code.

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
      "type": "serial",
      "theme": "light",
      "marginRight": 40,
      "marginLeft": 40,
      "autoMarginOffset": 20,
      "mouseWheelZoomEnabled": true,
      "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD",
      "dataLoader": {
          "url": base_url + "chart/get_all_data",
          "format": "json"
      },
      "categoryField": "date_created",
      "rotate": false, //Para sa sorting
      "categoryAxis": {
          "gridPosition": "start",
          "axisColor": "#DADADA"
      },
      "valueAxes": [{
          "id": "v1",
          "axisAlpha": 0,
          "position": "left",
          "ignoreAxisWidth": true
      }],
      "graphs": [{
          "id": "g1",
        "lineColor": "#29B4B6",
          "bullet": "round",
          "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
          "bulletColor": "#FFFFFF",
          "bulletSize": 5,
          "hideBulletsCount": 50,
          "lineThickness": 2,
          "title": "kWh",
          "useLineColorForBulletBorder": true,
          "valueField": "current_usage",
          "balloonText": "[[title]] in [[date_created]]:<b>[[current_usage]]</b>"
      }],
      "chartScrollbar": {
          "graph": "g1",
          "oppositeAxis": false,
          "offset": 30,
          "scrollbarHeight": 80,
          "backgroundAlpha": 0,
          "selectedBackgroundAlpha": 0.1,
          "selectedBackgroundColor": "#888888",
          "graphFillAlpha": 0,
          "graphLineAlpha": 0.5,
          "selectedGraphFillAlpha": 0,
          "selectedGraphLineAlpha": 1,
          "autoGridCount": true,
          "color": "#AAAAAA"
      },
      "chartCursor": {
          "pan": true,
          "valueLineEnabled": true,
          "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true,
          "cursorAlpha": 1,
          "cursorColor": "#258cbb",
          "limitToGraph": "g1",
          "valueLineAlpha": 0.2,
          "valueZoomable": true
      },
      "valueScrollbar": {
          "oppositeAxis": false,
          "offset": 50,
          "scrollbarHeight": 10
      },

      "categoryAxis": {
          "parseDates": true,
          "dashLength": 1,
          "minorGridEnabled": true
      },
      "export": {
          "enabled": true
      },
  });
```

thank you for the help. :( im still new in using amchart.
Here is my existing code

```
https://jsfiddle.net/rmallari/45hzatc3/9/
```

Comment: Its better if u start a fiddle here. https://jsfiddle.net/ with dummy data

Comment: hello mohammed sorry , thanks for the advice, here is the existing code. https://jsfiddle.net/rmallari/45hzatc3/9/

Answer (score 1):

Should follow the following things.

- Should serve data as array of objects with x axis value as mandatory.
- Add different line objects in graphs area.
- Each object should be unique on the basis of X-axis value (eg: shouldn't have different values for project1 and project2 in same day ).
- date_created should be in ASC format.

Running Script with 2 project lines

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
      "type": "serial",
      "theme": "light",
      "marginRight": 40,
      "marginLeft": 40,
      "autoMarginOffset": 20,
      "mouseWheelZoomEnabled": true,
      "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD",
      "dataProvider": [
        {
          "project_1": "20",
          "project_2": "10",
          "date_created": "2019-09-05 04:50:35"
        },
        {                   
          "project_1": "0",               
          "date_created": "2019-09-06 04:50:35"
        },
         {
          "project_1": "20",
          "project_2": "50",
          "date_created": "2019-09-07 04:50:35"
        },
        {
          "project_1": "140",
          "project_2": "7",
          "date_created": "2019-09-08 04:55:35"
        },
        {
          "project_1": "14",
          "project_2": "70",
          "date_created": "2019-09-09 04:50:35"
        },
        {
          "project_1": "50",
          "project_2": "0",
          "date_created": "2019-09-10 04:56:35"
        },              
        {
          "project_1": "60",
          "project_2": "0",
          "date_created": "2019-09-18 04:50:35"
        },
      ],
      "categoryField": "date_created",
      "rotate": false, //Para sa sorting
      "categoryAxis": {
          "gridPosition": "start",
          "axisColor": "#DADADA"
      },
      "valueAxes": [{
          "id": "v1",
          "axisAlpha": 0,
          "position": "left",
          "ignoreAxisWidth": true
      }],
      "graphs": [{
          "id": "g1",
        "lineColor": "#29B4B6",
          "bullet": "round",
          "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
          "bulletColor": "#FFFFFF",
          "bulletSize": 5,
          "hideBulletsCount": 50,
          "lineThickness": 2,
          "title": "kWh",
          "useLineColorForBulletBorder": true,
          "valueField": "project_1",
          "balloonText": "[[title]] in [[valueField]]:<b>[[project_1]]</b>"
      },
      {
          "id": "g2",
          "lineColor": "red",
          "bullet": "round",
          "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
          "bulletColor": "#FFFFFF",
          "bulletSize": 5,
          "hideBulletsCount": 50,
          "lineThickness": 2,
          "title": "kWh",
          "useLineColorForBulletBorder": true,
          "valueField": "project_2",
          "balloonText": "[[title]] in [[valueField]]:<b>[[project_2]]</b>"
      }],
      "chartScrollbar": {
          "graph": "g1",
          "oppositeAxis": false,
          "offset": 30,
          "scrollbarHeight": 80,
          "backgroundAlpha": 0,
          "selectedBackgroundAlpha": 0.1,
          "selectedBackgroundColor": "#888888",
          "graphFillAlpha": 0,
          "graphLineAlpha": 0.5,
          "selectedGraphFillAlpha": 0,
          "selectedGraphLineAlpha": 1,
          "autoGridCount": true,
          "color": "#AAAAAA"
      },
      "chartCursor": {
          "pan": true,
          "valueLineEnabled": true,
          "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true,
          "cursorAlpha": 1,
          "cursorColor": "#258cbb",
          "limitToGraph": "g1",
          "valueLineAlpha": 0.2,
          "valueZoomable": true
      },
      "valueScrollbar": {
          "oppositeAxis": false,
          "offset": 50,
          "scrollbarHeight": 10
      },

      "categoryAxis": {
          "parseDates": true,
          "dashLength": 1,
          "minorGridEnabled": true
      },
      "export": {
          "enabled": true
      },
  });
</script>
```

***[Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/8gba32k4/)***

Helpful ***[Link](https://www.amcharts.com/dataviz-tip-12-show-four-lines-line-chart/)*** Here.

Comment: hi, i already tried your solution, but what if my data is that will be fetch from the database is dynamic, so "project_id" will be dynamic to, if there is 5 unique project_id there should be 5 curves. is there a solution how will i implement it on the amchart. @Mohammed Shafeek

Comment: If project count is dynamic, You need to develop inputs and front end script by array transformation or looping.

Comment: Add schema here. It would help you to get a optimized query.

Comment: Hi @Mohammed Shafeek, here is my query,

`SELECT current_usage,project_id FROM electricity_usage` im still having a problem when regards on how to implement the looping with my query to amchart

Comment: Here you aren't mentioned anything about date field in query..Do update table schema used for expected graph in your question itself..not in comments..